# Не могу обновить Windows

Tags: windows, ос, обновление

Хочу обновить свою Windows XP на Windows 10. Вставил флешку с Windows 10, открываю `setup.exe` и ошибка — "Не является приложением Win 32". Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Windows XP у вас 32-битная, а setup.exe у вас 64-битный, который естественно не запустится. Почему бы не удалить Windows XP и не поставить Windows 10 на чистый диск?

Comment: надо сначала на Win7, потом на Win10

Comment: @PavelGridin Почему именно так?

Comment: так на microsoft-форумах спецы советуют, сам я этот путь проделывал постепенно и ещё прошёл через Win8

Comment: А зачем `setup.exe`, если можно сразу грузануться с флэшки?

Comment: @donRumata Как это сделать ,если вас не затруднит?

Comment: Эммм... как загрузиться с флэшки? Ну заходишь в BIOS, выбираешь первым загрузочным устройством флэшку, перезагружаешь комп, и собственно грузишься.